# How to display a seperate html page without using a component for routing in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I have an order page with component, HTMl and use routing to reach here. But once the order is submitted, I want to display a confirmation screen. This is a separate page but I donot have a component for this, its just a HTML page. How can I display this. I tried using windows.location.href

```
<button onclick="windows.location.href='xxx.html'"/>
```

But it doesnot work. Is there a way in Angular 2 to do this routing without a presence of component.

Comment: Is your page a static page outside of your application, or is it part of your application?

Comment: Looks like a typo - "windows.location" should be "window.location"

Comment: Hi Jean this page is a part of the application itself....

Comment: Hey Grey no not a type I tried with both its not going w tried this earlier as well but didn't work not sure if window.location works with angular 2 or not....

Comment: I tried this on my test button. And it worked. HTML:<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="goToTest()">TEST</button> TS: goToTest() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to open a new window?')) {
      window.open('test.html'); // or window.location.href = 'test.html';
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a component for this page to post it through routing couldnot find an option to just display an HTML without component